# How to insert Date and Time when a check box is checked in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I wrote a script that is working on edit and looking if the active cell in column A or column D. In column D I have a checkbox I want to fill the Column F with current time when the checkbox is true. You can see my script below. Currently it fills when column A is edited but It doesnt do anything if the checkbox is checked.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
   else if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
      if(r.getValue() == "TRUE") {
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try if(r.getValue()==true)

Answer (score 2):

- You want to put the date object to the column "F" when the checkbox at the column "D" is checked.
- You want to run the script with the OnEdit event trigger.

### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that the if statement of `if(r.getValue() == "TRUE") {}` is required to be modified. In this case, when `r.getValue()` is the boolean type, `r.getValue() == "TRUE"` is always `false`. By this, the script in the if statement is not run. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
if(r.getValue() == "TRUE") {
```

#### To:

```
if(r.getValue() === true) {
```

or

```
if(r.isChecked()) {
```

- In this case, also you can use `isChecked()`.

### Modified script 2:

When the event object is used, the process cost of your script can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546) The sample script using the event object is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1") {
    if(range.columnStart == 1) {
      var nextCell = range.offset(0, 4);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else if(range.columnStart == 4 && range.isChecked()) {
      var nextCell = range.offset(0, 2);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)